# AttributeError at /stories/6/segnala-commento/14/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'storia' Django

Tags: python, django

How i fix this error???

views.py

```
@login_required
def segnalaCommento(request, id, pk):
    a = get_object_or_404(A, id=a.b.id, pk=pk)
    a.segnala += 1
    a.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(a.b.get_absolute_url())
```

HTML Page

```
<a href="{% url 'fix-a' id=a.b.id pk=a.pk %}"><p>fix</p></a>
```

urls.py

```
path('<int:id>/fix-a/<int:pk>/', fixA, name="fix-a"),
```

Thank you

Comment: `commento = get_object_or_404(Commento, id=commento.storia.id, pk=pk)` makes no sense; you don't have a `commento` object to look up `commento.storia.id` from.

Comment: So how it should be???

Comment: I don't know, since I don't know your data model! What's the function supposed to do? Also, `id` and `pk` are in general aliases in Django unless you've customized things, so it's even harder to know what should be going on here. Looking at the HTML, maybe you're looking for a view that'd have `(request, storia_id, commento_id)`?

Comment: Practically yes

Comment: Why did you edit the question to hide the model names? Did you see my answer? Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so based on the comments, I guess you might want

```
@login_required
def segnalaCommento(request, storia_id, commento_id):
    commento = get_object_or_404(Commento, storia_id=storia_id, id=commento_id)
    commento.segnala += 1
    commento.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(commento.storia.get_absolute_url())
```

and

```
{% url 'segnala-commento' storia_id=commento.storia_id commento_id=commento.id %}
```

and

```
path('<int:storia_id>/segnala-commento/<int:commento_id>/', segnalaCommento, name="segnala-commento")
```

As an aside, do note that `commento.segnala += 1` is prone to race conditions if multiple users access the view concurrently. [This is explained very nicely in the Django documentation, with an example nearly identical to your use case.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)